# Heroku log errors

Tags: node.js

Trying to deploy Node.js app on heroku but getting following errors. Can anyone help me with where am I going wrong.

> 2018-06-29T00:01:21.641247+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
>       2018-06-29T00:01:21.641578+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the v1@1.0.0 start script.
>       2018-06-29T00:01:21.641895+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>       2018-06-29T00:01:21.660378+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>       2018-06-29T00:01:21.659090+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>       2018-06-29T00:01:21.660779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-06-29T00_01_21_645Z-debug.log
>       2018-06-29T00:01:21.758849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>       2018-06-29T00:01:21.736544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>       2018-06-29T00:01:22.688914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=campground-.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=7b46f802-439e-4038-85f4-882fbd765417 fwd="139.94.66.0"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>       2018-06-29T00:01:23.464401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=campground-.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=fe27806a-8390-431f-ba14-233625c388cf fwd="139.94.66.0"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>       2018-06-29T00:09:27.204098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>       2018-06-29T00:09:32.209782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
>       2018-06-29T00:09:35.411423+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>       2018-06-29T00:09:35.411450+00:00 app[web.1]: > v1@1.0.0 start /app
>       2018-06-29T00:09:35.411452+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
>       2018-06-29T00:09:35.411454+00:00 app[web.1]:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDjHS.png)

Comment: Could you please format the text of the logs appropriately?  Additionally could you attach the full output?  `npm` indicated your script failed above the first line in the image & the copied text.

Comment: Share your package.json